# Getting or Manipulating all cookies in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, cookies, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to mess with cookies using Chromedriver with Python (or Java).

I've figured out that

```
for cookie in browser.get_cookies():
    print(cookie['name'] + ' --> ' + cookie['value'])
```

only gives me the cookies relevant to the active page my browser's on.

Is there any method I can, using either Selenium or native Python (on Ubuntu, if I need to go into the file system), get all of the cookies on my active selenium session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide a userdir and extract the cookies from there.

```
co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
co.add_argument("--user-data-dir=userdir")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = co)
```

The cookies will end up in `userdir/Default/Cookies` which is an SQLite3 database.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use some http libraries with cookie inspection

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar),urllib2.HTTPHandler())
opener.get_method = lambda: 'GET'

request = urllib2.Request('http://stackoverflow.com/')
response = opener.open(request)

for cookie in cookieJar:
   print cookie
```

Comment: It's about Selenium not another library.