# Selenium Webdriver: Delete Cookies On All Domains

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

In selenium you can only delete cookies on the current domain, but would it be possible to navigate to the file where Firefox is storing the cookies and either delete the file or overwrite it? I've been looking around, but can't find where selenium stores the cookies.

Comment: What language are you using to give commands to selenium?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a user directory and then manipulate `<userdir>/Default/Cookies`. This question is similar: [Getting or Manipulating all cookies in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404670/getting-or-manipulating-all-cookies-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 2):

Selenium doesn't store the cookies, the browser does.  So the answer to "*where [the browser] stores the cookies*" will be different for each browser.  But since Selenium always starts the browser with a clean profile, you shouldn't have to do this - there are no cookies when the browser starts.

Comment: Selenium doesn't exactly "always start the browser with a clean profile" -- Selenium starts with a clean slate at the beginning of your test suite, but between individual tests, it simply deletes the cookies for whatever domain the browser currently points to.  So if your tests go to an external site, only the cookies on the domain you visited *last* will be reset for the next test.  If you need to clear cookies for more than one domain, you have to visit each domain, then delete the cookies manually, or do as @michael-w suggests and store the cookies somewhere on disk you can delete yourself