# Delete Mobile Safari Browser Cookies using Appium for IPAD and IPHONE real devices

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, mobile-safari, appium

I am facing issues while automating mobile safari through Appium+JAVA. How do I delete safari's browser cookies?

Comment: Do you have any code to show? What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver: Delete Cookies On All Domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127496/selenium-webdriver-delete-cookies-on-all-domains)

Answer (score 1):

Appium uses Selenium, so you'll want to **[read Selenium's documentation on Cookies](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#cookies)**. There's sample java code there as well.

Comment: What specifically did you try? Either there's a bug with Selenium or your implementation is incorrect. So, edit your question and show the code that's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Appium does not delete cookies beyond its current domain. To delete from other cookies as well provide the domain (ex: xyz.com in below code)

```
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
Iterator<Cookie> itr = cookies.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()){
Cookie c = itr.next();
driver.executeScript("document.cookie = " + c.getName() + "=; path=/; domain=xyz.com; 
         expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT;" );
 }
}
```

escape the semi colon in above string of executeScript method